# breaking down big java method into smaller methods

Tags: java

I have this messy and confusing method that I want to break down into smaller methods, but am having trouble getting the variables to carry over from one method to the other.  I'd like to break it down into a getStudentId() method and a getCourseId() method, but the user_Entered_student_Id is causing an issue.  Any quick tips would be appreciated

```
      public void signUp(){
    System.out.println("\nSign Up For a Class\n");
    try{
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");  
      String user_entered_student_id = input.nextLine();

      String userEnterId = "student_name" + (user_entered_student_id);

    System.out.println("Enter Class ID from Classes Listed Above to Join: ");

    String selectedClass = input.nextLine();

    student_x_class(selectedClass);
}
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void student_name(Scanner input,String user_entered_student_id, Statement myStmt, Connection con) {
    try{
    myStmt = con.createStatement();

    String query = ("SELECT student_name FROM ClassSelector.students WHERE student_id = " + user_entered_student_id);

    ResultSet rs;
    rs = myStmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
         String userEnterId = rs.getString("student_name");
         System.out.println("Is " + userEnterId + " the correct student? (Y/N)");

         String confirm = input.nextLine();

         if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
             getClass();
         }
         else if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("Oops, let start over");
         }
         return;
         }
}
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getClass(ResultSet rs, Statement myStmt){
        try{
            rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes");
            while (rs.next()) {
              String avlClasses = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("classname") + "\t" + rs.getString("description");
              System.out.println(avlClasses);
            }

          }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void student_x_class(Scanner input,String selectedClass, String userEnterId, String user_entered_student_id, ResultSet rs, Statement myStmt, Connection con){
        try{
         rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);

          while (rs.next()) {

          String innerJoin = (userEnterId + " has been added to " + rs.getString("classname") + " " + rs.getString("class_id"));
          System.out.println(innerJoin);

          String student_classJoin = "INSERT IGNORE INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id,student_name, class_id, classname)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
          PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(student_classJoin);
          pStmt.setString(1, user_entered_student_id);
          pStmt.setString(2, userEnterId);
          pStmt.setString(3, rs.getString("class_id"));
          pStmt.setString(4, rs.getString("classname"));
          pStmt.executeUpdate();
          System.out.println("Would you like to enroll " + userEnterId + " into another class? (Y/N)");
            String additionalClass = input.nextLine();
            if(additionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                signUp();
            }
        }
    }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: "user_Entered_student_Id is causing an issue"  , please elaborate

Comment: You can just pass that as a method parameter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may belong on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: when I split the method into two methods the user_enter_student_id "Cannot be resolved to variable".

Comment: As Suresh said, capture that input and store it as a variable in a common place; wherever you plan to call the methods from. Then pass it as a parameter to necessary methods.

Comment: @PeterO. don't vote to close because a question *may perhaps maybe* be better off asked on Code Review. Vote to close as *too broad* because it's *too broad* for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try!

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I can't retract my close vote and then add a new one.  Nor can I edit my close vote comment.

Comment: @PeterO. don't worry, there will be a "next time" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse you can select a bunch of code and do :

- Right clic
- Refactor
- Extract Method...

It's very helpful. But first make sure to only create variable just before you use them, not like your Statement created at the beginning of the method and used later.

Also don't reuse the same variable do to different things (I don't see the issue here but I haven't read it all) and don't create useless variables like "student_classJoin" or "additionalClass".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's a good thing that you feel you need to break this down into smaller, more manageable chunks. Knowing when someone needs refactoring is the first step towards success. You can congratulate yourself for that because a lot of people don't get to this point.

The next thing you should do is think about what the method does and break it up in your head into bits that have a single responsibility. (You don't need to do it in your head, you can also write it down in plain English.)

In your case your breakdown would look something like this:

- Select student

  - Ask for student id
  - Fetch student for database
  - Ask if this is correct student and start again if not
- Select class
- Add a student to a class
- Repeat all this if user wants to.

Now you can create a method for each of these steps (just empty method declarations, nothing more), and think about how these will fit together. What do you need to pass as a parameter, what should the method return.

When you're done with that too, you can fill out the bodies of the methods. As a bonus trick, you can first fill out the methods with dummy implementations, and you can then implement them one by one. So you can have something like this:

```
public String askForStudentId() {
    return "1";
}
```

Then you can write the rest of your code, and at some point return to this and replace it with:

```
public String askForStudentId() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    return input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me visualize what to do!  I've only been working with Java and MySQL for a month or so, so feedback like this is very helpful!  I'll work on it and get back to you!

Comment: I tried to implement the changes you suggested, and think I may be close, but am getting an error with the first section(the connection try-catch).  does this need to be moved into a method?

Also, this was part of a switch-statement with the signUp() Method as an option.  What would I use as that option now?

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: 1 for the encouragement, and proper guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the Java Object Oriented concepts. especially encapsulation.
I refactor your code but didn't have the tables and data to test, but you will get the general idea how to create different functions. with parameters and return type. More correction and refactoring needed in code, but i rewrite your code to get you the idea how to split code into different function and you can use them later also. One thing do not write whole query in the execute method, save the query in a string variable then pass it in the execute method, a more elegant way to write code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass
{

ResultSet rs;
PrepareStatement stmt;
Connection conn;
conn  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClassSelector?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "Volks91!");

public void signUp()
{

    System.out.println("\nSign Up For a Class\n");

    try
    {
        // getting user input. 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
        String user_entered_student_id = input.nextLine();

        /*
         Calling private methid in the class
         @param user_enter_student_id
         @return String userEnterID
         */
        String userEnterId = student_name(user_entered_student_id);

        // getting user input
        System.out.println("Enter Class ID from Classes Listed Above to Join: ");

        String selectedClass = input.nextLine();

        //calling method
        student_x_class(selectedClass);

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL)
    {
        SQL.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private string student_name(String user_entered_student_id)
{
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String query = "SELECT student_name FROM ClassSelector.students WHERE student_id = " + user_entered_student_id;

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next())
    {
        String userEnterId = rs.getString("student_name");
        System.out.println("Is " + userEnterId + " the correct student? (Y/N)");

        String confirm = input.nextLine();

        if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            getClass();

        } else if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            System.out.println("Oops, let start over");
            return;
        }
    }

    return userEnterId;
}

private void getClass()
{
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes");
    while (rs2.next())
    {
        String avlClasses = rs.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs.getString("classname") + "\t" + rs.getString("description");
        System.out.println(avlClasses);
    }
}

private void student_x_class(String selectedClass)
{
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);

    while (rs.next())
    {

        String innerJoin = (userEnterId + " has been added to " + rs.getString("classname") + " " + rs.getString("class_id"));
        System.out.println(innerJoin);

        String student_classJoin = "INSERT IGNORE INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id,student_name, class_id, classname)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(student_classJoin);
        Stmt.setString(1, user_entered_student_id);
        Stmt.setString(2, userEnterId);
        Stmt.setString(3, rs.getString("class_id"));
        Stmt.setString(4, rs.getString("classname"));
        Stmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Would you like to enroll " + userEnterId + " into another class? (Y/N)");
        String additionalClass = input.nextLine();
        if (additionalClass.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            signUp();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for this!  Everything seems to work except for the first reference to student_x_class, when you call selectedClass.  Is this because the student_x_class method is created after the method containing this?  How could I fix this?  Thank you again for the help!

Comment: I updated my code above.

Comment: There is nothing like numbering or ordering method or functions, why are you passing result set or other parameters?? declare them above contructre. Use dubugging, if you don't know how then use system.out.print to see upto which extend your code is working. Or send me the specific error you are getting.

Comment: I keep getting errors when I try to define the parameters in the Class heading I get errors, like "expected , but saw ;" which doesn't make sense.  I am getting this error

(The method student_x_class(Scanner, String, String, String, ResultSet, Statement, Connection) in the type ClassSelectorApp is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)) 

for the student_x_class and student_name method references in the signUp() method

Comment: The problem is your basics is weak I thing,
The function/ method should have same number of parameters when you call it. See where you calling the method. You write the 
student_x_class(selectedClass);
Where as when you decalere the method the parameters are differnt. 
public void student_x_class(Scanner input,String selectedClass, String userEnterId, String user_entered_student_id, ResultSet rs, Statement myStmt, Connection con).

the number of parameters must be same,
Check this link for learning. 

www.caveofprogramming.com and check java tutorials.

Comment: I see,thanks for the help.  I appreciate it